# Is allowing public access to a DNS server, a security threat?

Tags: dns, internet

If i was to create a DNS server that is hosted at my home, so then i can use it for my VPS servers; am I creating any security threat that can be abused by unknown clients from around the globe?

TL;DR:
If i set-up a DNS server, is it safe to open port 53 to the internet?

Comment: Not an answer to your question (it has been perfectly answered already), but an additional comment: you can have your server assessed by the Shadowserver Foundation: https://dnsscan.shadowserver.org/ . They will send you reports containing the amplification threat of your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some attack methods (especially *Dos/DDoS*) using DNS Servers such as; **[DrDoS](https://www.nbs-system.com/en/blog/ddos-how-does-it-work/)** and **[DNS Amplification](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A)** but there are also ways to ***strengthen*** your DNS Server and the connection between server and VPSs.

- **[DNSCrypt](https://dnscrypt.org/#about)** is one of them (and I *highly* suggest you to use it by default) used especially for preventing **[DNS Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing)**.
- Also, I suggest you to install and configure a good firewall on your server (*Windows Firewall* on Windows and *[ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)* on Linux can be used) which allow only your VPS IP addresses to access your DNS server; other incoming traffic should be '***denied***' by default. If you want not only your VPS Servers but also others may send a *DNS request*, you may use ***Limit*** option to set limits to prevent excessive traffic.
- **IPS** and **IDS** applications/programs can be also used to *detect* and *prevent* some attack vectors but they mostly require a little technical knowledge. [**Snort**](https://www.snort.org/), **[Surricata](https://suricata-ids.org)** and **[Bro IDS](https://www.bro.org)**.
- At the end, you may want to use a *log management and monitoring system* (there are dozens of log management and monitor system available both open source and paid ones).

Note: There are some readings that you may use it to develop your understanding about DNS Server security practices:

1. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770432(v=ws.11).aspx
2. https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/dns/security-issues-dns-1069
3. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/security-center/dns-best-practices.html
4. [What can and can't a malicious DNS do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/what-can-and-cant-a-malicious-dns-do)
5. [Listing of DNS vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/listing-of-dns-vulnerabilities)
6. https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/sei_blog/2017/02/six-best-practices-for-securing-a-robust-domain-name-system-dns-infrastructure.html

Answer (score 0):

An improperly configured DNS server can be used inside a [DNS amplification attack](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A) to attack other systems. Apart from that the DNS server itself might have security problems which can be for example used for code execution and from there to attacking your internal network. See for example the [list of CVE for bind](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/144/ISC-Bind.html?vendor_id=64), one of the major DNS server implementations.

Comment: Is there any source on the internet, that i could use to learn about making my DNS server more secure?

Comment: @Bumbalaga: There are various resources about this topic. Have you already tried to [use a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=secure+dns+server)?